# Why does the PDF turn out to be single spaced even though the source was double spaced?

Tags: spacing

I just downloaded my university's dissertation template from https://graduate.utdallas.edu//current_students/dissertation_and_thesis/ . To get the document in that page please click "Latex Template". It includes a .cls file, a sample .tex and the .pdf output. It is compilable, my pdf output is single spaced, but everyone else including the template author have the double space, so it must be my problem. (I try to run it in `TeXstudio`, the log shows a bad box `Underfull \vbox (badness 2384) has occurred while \output is active` but I think this might be irrelevant?)

[image: clearly you can see that my pdf output is single space]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's much easier for potential helpers here to investigate a problem when code is included as a "code block" in the text rather than as a scan.  You can copy and paste the code, then highlight it and click on the `{}` icon above the box where you are entering your question.

Comment: Hi Barbara, if you read my question description, you would know that the cls is 100% correct, it is right in the link I quoted. It must be the case that I wrongly set something in Miktex... thanks for your point though.

Comment: But you are more likely to get answers if you give us code that we can copy and paste, not hidden behind a link.  How does your tex file differ from the template?  If you download and compile the template, is that still double spaced?  Or is it only your attempt at using the template that is turning out to be double spaced?  Your link takes us to the template.  How are we supposed to figure out what you've done or not done to make your file double spaced or not?

Comment: I do not think it is your problem.  I compiled `sample.tex` and the output is single spaced.  Follow their advice: `For LaTex technical questions, you may contact Dr. Kevin Hamlen`

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, while the class is being corrected add

`\def\baselinestretch{1.655}\selectfont`  or

`\linespread{1.655}\selectfont`

after `\maketitle` and before `\begin{acks}`

to (mostly) reproduce the `sample.pdf`

From

[image: c]

To

[image: d]

```
\maketitle

\linespread{1.655}\selectfont  % <<<<  added

\begin{acks}{December 2012} % date when thesis first submitted to committee
The author thanks Amanda Aiuvalasit and Wanda Trotta in the Office of the
Graduate Dean for their time proofing sample documents produced by this
class file and reexamining various details of the UTD thesis guidelines
that arose during its creation.
\end{acks}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Simon!!! Appreciated your help! But hours before, I just tried to compile it on online OVERLEAF editor, it is double spaced... wondering if you could give a try on OVERLEAF?